# Only fetch data from Firestore once on app start, distribute it from there

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So far I've used a mock containing an array from which the whole app got its data from, by iterating through it. Works fine.

```
export const CASES: Case[] = [
  { id: 0,
    name: 'Diesel',
    portfolioImage: '/assets/images/portfolio/diesel.png',
    image: '/assets/images/diesel.jpg',
    image2: '/assets/images/diesel/diesel-sunflower.png',
    image3: '/assets/images/diesel/diesel-cap.png',
    link: '/cases/diesel',
    header: 'black'
  },

  { id: 1,
    name: 'WeWork Berlin',
    portfolioImage: '/assets/images/portfolio/berlin.png',
    image: '/assets/images/berlin.jpg',
    image2: '/assets/images/wework/berlin-logo.png',
    image3: '/assets/images/wework/berlin-building.png',
    link: '/cases/wework',
    header: 'white'
  }
];
```

Currently I'm trying to connect my app to Firestore. To get data from Firestore I used the following code inside of my desired component:

```
export class PortfolioComponent implements OnInit {

  cases;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.db.collection('entries').valueChanges()
      .subscribe(val => this.cases = val);
  }

}
```

It works, but I want to only call this once - to be exact is there a way to fetch the data on app init..

- and either insert it into the mock I've used before,
- or insert the data into an array which can be used globally

Doing so I want to achieve to only have to fetch the data once, insert it and distribute it from there. Just like I've done it without Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fetch data on app init, you have to use `APP_INITIALIZER` which is an built in `InjectionToken` instance. Sample of `app.module.ts` would be:

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { AppInitService } from './app-init.service';

export function initializeApp1(appInitService: AppInitService) {
  return (): Promise<any> => { 
    return appInitService.Init();
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [ 
    AppInitService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER,useFactory: initializeApp1, deps: [AppInitService], multi: true}
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In your `AppInitService` you should make a request that will fetch data and you should keep it, if you're using NGRX in your store, if not, in some singleton root service. When you fetch data, you should return promise that will resolve.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppInitService {

  // note dataSerice is service where you'll hold your data on fetch
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, private dataService: DataService) { }

  Init(): Promise<any> {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
this.db.collection('entries').valueChanges()
      .subscribe(val => {
         this.dataService.data = val; // assign data to data service
         resolve(true);
      });
     })
  }
}
```

Now, in this case, inject `dataService: DataService` anywhere you need and you'll have your `data` stored in data property.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.